# Bings Map API needs getTMC, not described on documentation

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I'm trying to use the Bings Map API, but keeps getting the error:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441726

```
getTMCs: This parameter value has an invalid format
```

Looking through the doc's says nothing about the parameter getTMCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was also asked on the Bing Maps MSDN forums. There it was discovered that an incorrectly formatted REST URL was returning two errors messages. The issue has since been resolved. Full details can be found here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89e0157a-99ad-48f6-be12-1cef8824d087/bings-map-api-needs-gettmc-not-described-on-documentation?forum=bingmapsservices